Could not resolve all files for configuration ':connectivity_plus:androidJdkImage'
I am working on a Flutter project and recently upgraded my Android Studio, Java versions and also the gradle version in gradle-wrapper.properties file to the latest
In gradle-wrapper.properties file:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.10.2-all.zip

Error log while building app:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':connectivity_plus:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':connectivity_plus:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/..../Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process /Users/..../Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /Users/malwinder/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/057cd3d70c61a40076a3bbfe497a8e16-0d4425f6-230d-4e42-a5da-d5def5f24a35/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /Users/..../.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/057cd3d70c61a40076a3bbfe497a8e16-0d4425f6-230d-4e42-a5da-d5def5f24a35/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

Android Studio:
Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1
Build #AI-242.21829.142.2421.12409432, built on September 25, 2024
Runtime version: 21.0.3+-79915917-b509.11 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Toolkit: sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit
macOS 15.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Concurrent GC, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 8
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
  ide.balloon.shadow.size=0
  debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
  ide.new.editor.tabs.vertical.borders=true
  ide.animate.toolwindows=true
  ide.experimental.ui=true
  ide.editor.tab.selection.animation=true
  i18n.locale=
Non-Bundled Plugins:
  com.chylex.intellij.inspectionlens (1.4.1)
  com.jetbrains.gerryPurpleTheme (2024.1.0920)
  com.zll.format (2.2)
  IdeaVIM (2.16.0)
  dev.willebrands.intellij.sloppyfocus (0.9.0)
  Dart (242.21829.3)
  PlantUML integration (7.11.2-IJ2023.2)
  com.bloc.intellij_generator_plugin (4.0.2)
  com.flutter_create_stateful_widget (1.5)
  andrasferenczi.dart-data-plugin (0.2.0)
  com.markskelton.one-dark-theme (5.12.0)
  com.ankit.mahadik.json.dart.class (2.16)
  com.intellij.marketplace (242.21829.233)
  com.localizely.flutter-intl (1.18.5-2023.2)
  Key Promoter X (2024.2.0)
  com.herbert.george.dart.extensions (0.0.1+3)
  com.jiajun.flutter_add_image (1.7)
  com.shuzijun.markdown-editor (2.0.5)
  com.herbert.george.flutter-snippets (2.0.0-stable-1)
  com.eggnstone.jetbrainsplugins.DartFormat (2.0.20)
  Docker (242.21829.162)
  izhangzhihao.rainbow.brackets (2024.2.6-241)
  cn.yiiguxing.plugin.translate (3.6.6)
  pl.pszklarska.pubversionchecker (1.3.5)
  com.chrisrm.idea.MaterialThemeUI (9.5.0)
  com.developerphil.adbidea (1.6.18)
  com.github.kikimanjaro.stickyscroll (0.0.2)
  com.github.copilot (1.5.24.6927-nightly)
  org.intellij.qodana (242.21829.57)
  com.mallowigi (97.0.0)
  mobi.hsz.idea.gitignore (4.5.3)
  io.flutter (81.1.3)
  com.crzsc.FlutterAssetsGenerator (2.4.2)
  de.mariushoefler.flutter_enhancement_suite (1.7.1)
  com.ruiyu.ruiyu (5.2.1)

Running MacOS Sequoia (Version 15.0)
I think this issue is related to https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus package
More details: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/3299

did you already try flutter clean and flutter pub get ?

Which Android Gradle Plugin are you using? I mean, com.android.application, you can find version in android/settings.gradle

and since you just upgrading your gradle and java, make sure they are compatible each other (agp, gradle, kotlin, java, android studio) check the compability version in AGP Compability and Android Compability

Fixed issue by using:
   id "com.android.application" version "8.7.0" apply false

in plugins block In android/settings.gradle
Also set in gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.10.2-all.zip

Currently using Java version:
java version "1.8.0_301"


Can use the AGP Upgrade assistant in Tools of Android Studio also

the accepted answer doesn't work for me, but finally I figured it out by this command:
flutter config --jdk-dir  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/home

change the argument to your own JDK path.

Oh my god, thank you so much!
I spent literally 6 days to fix this issue. I checked a lot of answers around stack overflow and more other links while googling. Nothing helped and I never saw answers like yours before. I had no clue what should I do for now. You're my savior!

To solve this problem, you need to download the java 17 in your pc. Then setup the java in your pc. Then you need to the java path. Now open the studio and delete the 35 SDK if you download. (Flutter is not support the 35 SDK till now)
Open the terminal from android studio and command
flutter config --jdk-dir (path of java 17 here)

Let go to the android/app/build.gradle file
from
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

to
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

Now clean the invalid cache for android studio and run the project
I had solved my problem using this. I am using linux.
